# Is there a way to seed data in a table created via declarative schema in Magento 2.3?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Created a custom table in Magento 2.3 using the new declarative schema method, which worked great in terms of creating the table, except I can't figure out how to seed data into the table when it's created. Is there a different method for adding data than using InstallData.php?

Prior to the declarative schema method, it was done with an InstallSchema.php  and an InstallData.php file.

I've tried using my InstallData.php file along with the declarative schema, as I wasn't able to find a replacement method for InstallData.php (along the lines of how db_schema.xml replaced InstallSchema.php) documented anywhere.

Here's my db_schema.xml:

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sports" resource="default" engine="innodb"
        comment="Sports Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="sport_id" identity="true" unsigned="true" nullable="false" primary="true" comment="Sport Id" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="sport_name" length="255" nullable="false" default="" comment="Sport Name" />
        <index referenceId="SPORTS_SPORT_ID" indexType="btree">
            <column name="sport_id"/>
        </index>
    </table>
 </schema>
```

And here's the important bits of my InstallData.php:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
          /**
           * Install messages
           */
          $data = [
              ['sport_name' => 'Hockey'],
              ['sport_name' => 'MMA']
          ];
          foreach ($data as $bind) {
              $setup->getConnection()
                ->insertForce($setup->getTable('sports'), $bind);
          }
    }
```

I would expect the table to generate populated with data as it did using the old method. Instead I'm getting the table to show up, but without any data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
namespace Bilal\Cruddemo\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $_cruddemoFactory;

    public function __construct(\Bilal\Cruddemo\Model\CruddemoFactory $cruddemoFactory)
    {
        $this->_cruddemoFactory = $cruddemoFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $data = [
            'sport_name' => 'Hockey',
            'sport_name' => 'MMA'
        ];

        $this->_cruddemoFactory->create()->setData($data)->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Deleted my table and removed my custom module from the db and tried again with the new code. I got the same result wherein my table showed up but without any data.

Comment: Sorry, apparently the code didn't post for some reason. Apparently, there's a character limit on comments, so here's a link to the file: [link](https://github.com/vaquerochris/magentotest/blob/master/Setup.php)

Comment: I have update my answer please check it and if it solve your problem accept it.Can we talk on other platform?